# PIC16F877A latchup/glitching

Tags: microcontroller, pic, oscillator

I have a PIC16F877A microcontroller with a 19.6608 MHz crystal, wired for 12V ICSP. I can reprogram the chip just fine, and it runs almost flawlessly (it's blinking an LED right now as I type). Only thing is, the PIC seems to latch up or stop its oscillator when I get up from my chair and touch the metal frame of the table it is sitting on. I sit back down, touch the metal frame again, and the PIC starts blinking the LED again. Sometimes it takes more than one "cycle" to get the PIC started again. Weird...

I made sure to select the right oscillator mode (HS), disable the watchdog timer, set unused pins to outputs, use decoupling capacitors, etc. I made sure I selected the correct capacitors for the crystal I'm using.

Any suggestions as to the cause of this flakiness?

Comment: In the year 2013, Microchip will sell you a microcontroller that has a built-in oscillator.

Comment: Can you post a picture of how you built this? PCB? Breadboard?

Comment: @Kaz Build yourself a clock or try RS232 with a built-in oscillator and tell me how it goes.

Comment: I built a clock with an external osc. recently! Problem is, it stops whenever I touch the desk ...

Comment: @user1354999 Some MCUs do quite well with internal oscillators for serial communications. The AVR XMEGA series definitely work reliably for this purpose.

Comment: Do you have a picture of this set up?

Answer (score 2):

The most likely culprit is the reset input is not pulled high (or low, cannot remember) with a resistor to keep noise from triggering it.  Look at the default circuits for PIC MCUs for the reset input.

Comment: +1. The reset input in question is the MCLR pin (master clear, active-low), which needs to be pulled high. See section 14.4 of the 18f87xA datasheet.